# An asset packaging tool for plain old java (like Android's R class)

Tags: java, android, aapt, dynamic-class

I was impressed by the way android creates an `R` class during development. I do my development in Android Studio (which basically is a tuned IntelliJ version). Whenever I add a resource, in a matter of seconds the `R` class is updated with new fields.

When I develop in my plain old java projects, I am having the same desires. Instead of creating many `public static final String` declarations. I would like to have something like the dynamicly created `R` class. For obvious reasons of course: less chance on typos.

I started to wonder how they achieved this, because just like in Android development, I have a java project with many resources (i.e. `String` declarations) in custom XML files. I would love to setup something which processes my custom XML files and creates a dynamic class during development.

The javadoc of Android's generated `R` class reveals that it was generated using the **AAPT tool**. (which stands for Android Asset Packaging Tool). So, I am **wondering if something similar exists for plain old java projects.**